# Inspect who change a model rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-audited

I have a Rails 3 application with a loads of models. Also i have a loads of rake tasks and more. At least i have a necessary to inspect all changes in my database. Each time when record changes i have to know which line of script made a change.

I used to use audited-gem, that's fine, but doesn't answer about initiator of changes, and that's make me sad. I'm really stuck with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use acts_as_audited for this, it's just called "Audited" now -

https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited

This works fine but didn't record the user that made the change when the change was made via the console or a rake task, as you say.  So, i came up with a quite hacky solution (which works fine for us, but may be system-dependent) for recording the user on our production server.

At the company where I work, there are two rails devs.  We're the only people that ever ssh onto our production server, and we have our public rsa keys stored on the server, in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

When I ssh on, my key is read, and i can actually do some more things, like set environment variables.  So, we both modified our keys, as stored on the server, to look like this

```
#mine
environment="railsid=1182" ssh-rsa <keystring> <computer name>

#my colleague's
environment="railsid=1" ssh-rsa <keystring> <computer name>
```

1182 and 1 are the ids of our user records on the system.  This will set an environment variable of "railsid" to either "1182" or "1", depending on which of us is logged in.  (we both log in as the same user on the server - this is the user that the app runs in so it's easier for permissions etc if we both just use that)

I then modified the code of acts_as_audited:  normally it gets the current logged in user, like so:

```
def set_audit_user
  if Thread.current[:acts_as_audited_user]
    self.user = Thread.current[:acts_as_audited_user] 
  end
  nil # prevent stopping callback chains
end
```

My change was to see, if there's no current user, if that environment variable had been set, and if so, to use that as the user for the audit record:

```
def set_audit_user
  if Thread.current[:acts_as_audited_user]
    self.user = Thread.current[:acts_as_audited_user] 
  elsif ENV['railsid'] && u = User.find_by_id(ENV['railsid'])
    self.user = u
  end
  nil # prevent stopping callback chains
end
```

We've been using acts_as_audited for a long time - we installed it as a plugin rather than a gem, so i made this change in `vendor/plugins/acts_as_audited/lib/acts_as_audited/audit.rb`

If you wanted to do this too, you'd be using the gem instead, so you'd need to make a monkey patch,eg in your lib folder.  (i've got a file `lib/gem_extensions.rb` which i use for stuff like this).

Like i say, this is super-hacky, but it works :)

Comment: Great! Thank you a lot! It's not solve problem with count of scripts, and inspect which of them change the records, but solving my another task. Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about the requirements for "Each time when record changes i have to know which line of script made a change.".  Do you only want this to happen as part of a rake task?  Theoretically you could look at the `caller` object inside acts_as_audited too, eg `caller[0]` to get the line of code calling the method.  However, this can often prove difficult as `caller` is the stack trace, and your rake task could be many steps away from the acts_as_audited method.  I suppose you could look at `caller` and look for the first file to be in your 'lib/tasks' folder.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the gem you mentioned works. [Papertrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) keeps a record of who made the data change using the controller and current_user variable. See their Github page.

Comment: yeah, audited works like a Papertrail. It also keep a current_user, but it doesn't work when changes made by rake task.